# Unknown type name array

Tags: macos, graphics, metal

I have a metal 2 shader on macOS 10.12 that I am trying to pass an array of int into, but XCode is giving me a compile-time error `Unknown type name 'array'`. Here is the code I am using:

```
kernel void computeMandelbrot(texture2d<float, access::write> output [[texture(0)]], constant int &maxIterations [[buffer(1)]], const array<int, 10> &hist [[buffer(2)]], uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
// Compute Mandelbrot
}
```

I have also tried using the keyword `constant` instead of `const` but then I also get an error of `Parameter may not be qualified with an address space`. I had read that arrays of textures were not supported in metal on macOS, but I was not sure if this appled to arrays of other types. Any help would be greatly appriciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- Metal **2** is not available in macOS 10.12. It is new with 10.13.
- <del>`array` is only usable with textures and samplers.</del>
- `array` is not available on macOS <=10.12. It's available on macOS 10.13+ with Metal 2.
- You can declare your parameter as `constant int *hist [[buffer(2)]]`. It won't have an explicit length, but just limit what elements you reference.

Edit: I was wrong about `array` only being usable with textures and samplers. The spec suggests that to be the case by introducing it in a section titled "Arrays of Textures and Samplers" and only illustrating its use that way, but the template class itself seems generically useful.

However, until Metal 2, it's not available on macOS. In other words, it's only available on macOS 10.13+.